# Why passing Int => Int to a function taking AnyVal => Int results in type mismatch when Int extends AnyVal?

Tags: scala, contravariance

I'm new to scala and I'm having some hard time with passing a func as a parameter to a different func.  The function that I'm trying to pass should get an argument but I dont know its type (but its a value defenitly):

```
object Sing
    def myFunc(myinnerfunc:(AnyVal)=>Int):Anyval
    {
    ...
    }

object main {
  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit ={
    val a = Sing.myFunc((x:Int)=>2*x:Int)
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is :

```
type mismatch : 
found : (Int)=>Int
required : (AnyVal)=>Int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the fact that `Int` extends `AnyVal`, the function `myFunc` cannot accept `Int => Int` because in Scala function is

> [contravariant](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html#other-examples) over its argument type, and covariant over its
>   return type

which means `Int => Int` is **not** a subtype of `AnyVal => Int`

```
implicitly[(Int => Int) <:< (AnyVal => Int)]   // Error: Cannot prove
```

If you know the function argument is of numeric type, then consider [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) typeclass solution

```
def myFunc[T](myinnerfunc: T => Int)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = ???
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't know its type so a generic type should be used. AnyVal is not guaranteed to be an Int so you can't just pass a function with Int:

```
def myFunc[T <: AnyVal](myinnerfunc: T => Int): Any = 0

myFunc((_: Int) * 2)
```